# C - Arrays And Pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to compile and run my below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        int (*x)[7];
        int a[7] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int i = 0;
        x=a;
        for (i=0; i < 7 ; i++)
                printf("%d\n", x[i]);
}
```

As per the code I am creating a pointer x pointing to a memory location having seven continuous memory block to store integers.

But I keep getting compiler warnings and erroneous output:

```
desktop:~$ gcc a1.c 
a1.c: In function ‘main’:
a1.c:6:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
a1.c:6:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘a’) [enabled by default]
a1.c:8:3: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
a1.c:10:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

desktop:~$ ./a.out 
-1081431716
-1081431688
-1081431660
-1081431632
-1081431604
-1081431576
-1081431548
```

Why these warnings and output are coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the warnings one by one.

**Issue 1**

> a1.c:6:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]

Line 6 is the following statement:

```
int a[7] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

You're defining an array of `int`s with a length of **7** and initializing it with **8** values.

The solution to this should be pretty obvious.

**Issue 2**

> a1.c:8:3: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Line 8 is the following statement:

```
x=a;
```

`x` is defined like this:

```
int (*x)[7];
```

You are defining `x` to be a pointer to a *1D* array of 7 `int`s.  This kind of definition is needed when accessing *2D* arrays.

To remove the warning you must do one of the following two things:

```
/* Option 1 */
int *x;
x = a;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    printf("%d\n", x[i]);

/* Option 2 */
int (*x)[7];
x = &a;
for (i=0; i < 7 ; i++)
    printf("%d\n", x[0][i]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this statement

```
    int (*x)[7];
```

to

```
    int *x;
```

This `int (*x)[7];` is a declaration of a pointer to an object that has type `int[7]`. So for example expression x[1] will have address `7 * sizeof( int )` greater than the address that is stored in x. It is not what you want.

Also array a has more initializers (=8) than its dimension (=7)

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`.

The correct program will look as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
        const int N = 8; 
        int *x;
        int a[N] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int i;

        x = a;
        for ( i = 0; i < N ; i++)
                printf( "%d\n", x[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `int (*x)[7];` to `int (*x)[8];` and

```
x = &a;            // Assign the address of array to x because it is a pointer to an array of 8 int
printf("%d\n", x[i]);   
               ^Pointer to first element of ith row
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", (*x)[i]);
```

Comment: Why we need to make it [8] instead of [7]. Thanks the output comes fine but I still get warnings : a1.c: In function ‘main’:
a1.c:6:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
a1.c:6:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘a’) [enabled by default]
a1.c:8:3: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: @Prakash; Read the first line of the answer.

Comment: Down voter should explain the reason for the down vote.

Comment: down voter probably doesnt actually know C (since he only downvoted correct answers)

Comment: @Prakash; Because `x[i]` is giving you address not the elements value.

Comment: Not the down voter, but it appears to be someone who thinks this is a bad question and should not be answered and is therefore down voting all answers to this question.

Comment: @wolfPack88; Then I think the downvoter could be a pointer expert.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int *x;
        int a[8] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int i = 0;
        x=a;
        for (i=0; i < 8 ; i++) //Loop boundary is 0 to 7
           printf(" %d\n",*(x+i)); /* This prints the value contained
                                      in i'th place */
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a[7] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

You have 8 initializers in your 7 elements array.

> (C99, 6.7.8p1) "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized."

Then if you want to iterate on the array elements, you don't need a pointer to the array (your `x` declaration) just use:

```
    for (i=0; i < 7 ; i++)
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks - got the issue in my code but why the output was coming junk?

Comment: There's a good chance this is homework that is trying to demonstrate pointers, so "you don't need a pointer" probably isn't a viable answer.

Comment: @AndrewMedico well in that case, `int *x = a;` then `printf("%d\n", x[i]);`

Comment: @Prakash the code you showed is invalid, invalid code may show invalid output.